# Problem with showing UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: iphone

In my UIViewController view I take

1. A tab bar
2. Tab bar button
3. Table view
4. Button
5. UIActivityIndicatorView

When I press a button that time I reload the table data and that time I want to show an indicator but when table is reloaded that time indicator not working .

When I press the button I properly start the indicator `[indicator startAnimating];` but it's not working.

I thing I forgot some thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's also possible that you added it the view before adding the tableview, and thus the tableview is on top of it, obscuring it.  Make sure you add the indicator to the view after adding the uitableview.

If you did all this in IB, then in your view controller, in the viewDidLoad method, add this line:

```
 [self.view bringSubviewToFront:indicator];
```

You might also consider - just to get going again - using the status bar activity indicator.

```
 [UIApplication sharedApplication]. networkActivityIndicatorVisible =  YES;
  ... network call ...
 [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
```

Comment: is there any problem for indicator while communication with the server.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the indicator has either been placed , with the proper outlet set in IB, or has been programmatically created, with a proper frame, and added to a visible view.

This indicator may be hidden, try adding `indicator.hidden = NO;`. 
It's also possible that if you added it to the tableview, and that location is not visible after scrolling. This is because the indicator's frame would be fixed inside the tableview's, and not screen's, coordinates.